# SFTP with chroot depending on public key of connecting user

Tags: linux, ssh, freebsd, sftp, ssh-keys

I want to build a server (running Debian or FreeBSD) that receives backups from different clients via sshfs. Each client should be able to read and write its own backup data, but not the data of any of the other clients.

I had the following idea: each client connects via public key auth to backup@backupserver.local. The user *backup* has a special authorized_keys file, like this:

```
command="internal-sftp" chroot="/backup/client-1/data" ssh-rsa (key1)
command="internal-sftp" chroot="/backup/client-2/data" ssh-rsa (key2)
command="internal-sftp" chroot="/backup/client-3/data" ssh-rsa (key3)
etc...
```

The advantage of this would be that I would not need to use a separate user for every client, and I could easily autogenerate the authorized_keys file with a script.

There is just one problem: the `chroot=...` does not work. OpenSSH's authorized_keys file does not seem to have an equivalent for ChrootDirectory (which works in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, either globally or in a Match User block).

Is there a reasonably simple way to accomplish what I want using OpenSSH? Maybe using the `command=...` directive in a clever way?
Alternatively, are there other SFTP servers that can do what I want?

**EDIT**: To make it more clear what I want to achieve: I want several clients to be able to store files on my server. Each client should not be able to see any other client's files. And I do not want to litter my server with dozens of user accounts, so I'd like an easily manageable solution for the clients to share a user account and still have no access to eachother's files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Alternatively, are there other SFTP servers that can do what I want?

yes, you can use proftpd

Prepare user environment. With ProFTPD there is no need to give to user a valid shell.

```
# useradd -m -d /vhosts/backup/user1/ -s /sbin/nologin user1
# passwd --lock user1
Locking password for user user1.
passwd: Success

# mkdir /vhosts/backup/user1/.sftp/
# touch /vhosts/backup/user1/.sftp/authorized_keys

# chown -R user1:user1 /vhosts/backup/user1/
# chmod -R 700 /vhosts/backup/user1/
```

In order to use OpenSSH public keys in a SFTPAuthorizedUserKeys, you must convert them to the RFC4716 format. You can do this with ssh-keygen tool:

```
# ssh-keygen -e -f user1.public.key > /vhosts/backup/user1/.sftp/authorized_keys
```

Setup ProFTPD

```
ServerName "ProFTPD Default Installation"
ServerType standalone
DefaultServer off

LoadModule mod_tls.c
LoadModule mod_sftp.c
LoadModule mod_rewrite.c

TLSProtocol TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2

# Disable default ftp server
Port 0

UseReverseDNS off
IdentLookups off

# Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new dirs and files
# from being group and world writable.
Umask 022

# PersistentPasswd causes problems with NIS/LDAP.
PersistentPasswd off

MaxInstances 30

# Set the user and group under which the server will run.
User nobody
Group nobody

# Normally, we want files to be overwriteable.
AllowOverwrite                  on

TimesGMT off
SetEnv TZ :/etc/localtime

<VirtualHost sftp.example.net>
    ServerName "SFTP: Backup server."
    DefaultRoot ~
    Umask 002
    Port 2121

    RootRevoke on

    SFTPEngine on
    SFTPLog /var/log/proftpd/sftp.log

    SFTPHostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
    SFTPHostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
    SFTPDHParamFile /etc/pki/proftpd/dhparam_2048.pem
    SFTPAuthorizedUserKeys file:~/.sftp/authorized_keys

    SFTPCompression delayed
    SFTPAuthMethods publickey
</VirtualHost>

<Global>
    RequireValidShell off
    AllowOverwrite yes

    DenyFilter \*.*/

    <Limit SITE_CHMOD>
        DenyAll
    </Limit>
</Global>

LogFormat default "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b"
LogFormat auth    "%v [%P] %h %t \"%r\" %s"
ExtendedLog /var/log/proftpd/access.log read,write
```

Create DH (Diffie-Hellman ) group parameters.

```
# openssl dhparam -out /etc/pki/proftpd/dhparam_2048.pem 2048
```

Configure any SFTP client. I have used FileZilla

[image: FileZilla SFTP server settings]

If you run ProFPTD in debug mode

```
# proftpd -n -d 3
```

In the console you will see something like the following

```
2016-02-21 22:12:48,275 sftp.example.net proftpd[50511]: using PCRE 7.8 2008-09-05
2016-02-21 22:12:48,279 sftp.example.net proftpd[50511]: mod_sftp/0.9.9: using OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
2016-02-21 22:12:48,462 sftp.example.net proftpd[50511] sftp.example.net: set core resource limits for daemon
2016-02-21 22:12:48,462 sftp.example.net proftpd[50511] sftp.example.net: ProFTPD 1.3.5a (maint) (built Sun Feb 21 2016 21:22:00 UTC) standalone mode STARTUP
2016-02-21 22:12:59,780 sftp.example.net proftpd[50512] sftp.example.net (192.168.1.2[192.168.1.2]): mod_cap/1.1: adding CAP_SETUID and CAP_SETGID capabilities
2016-02-21 22:12:59,780 sftp.example.net proftpd[50512] sftp.example.net (192.168.1.2[192.168.1.2]): SSH2 session opened.
2016-02-21 22:12:59,863 sftp.example.net proftpd[50512] sftp.example.net (192.168.1.2[192.168.1.2]): Preparing to chroot to directory '/vhosts/backup/user1'
2016-02-21 22:12:59,863 sftp.example.net proftpd[50512] sftp.example.net (192.168.1.2[192.168.1.2]): Environment successfully chroot()ed
2016-02-21 22:12:59,863 sftp.example.net proftpd[50512] sftp.example.net (192.168.1.2[192.168.1.2]): USER user1: Login successful
```

And the follwoing lines in a /var/log/sftp.log

```
2016-02-21 22:12:48,735 mod_sftp/0.9.9[50309]: sending acceptable userauth methods: publickey
2016-02-21 22:12:48,735 mod_sftp/0.9.9[50309]: public key MD5 fingerprint: c2:2f:a3:93:59:5d:e4:38:99:4b:fd:b1:6e:fc:54:6c
2016-02-21 22:12:48,735 mod_sftp/0.9.9[50309]: sending publickey OK
2016-02-21 22:12:59,789 mod_sftp/0.9.9[50309]: public key MD5 fingerprint: c2:2f:a3:93:59:5d:e4:38:99:4b:fd:b1:6e:fc:54:6c
2016-02-21 22:12:59,790 mod_sftp/0.9.9[50309]: sending userauth success
2016-02-21 22:12:59,790 mod_sftp/0.9.9[50309]: user 'user1' authenticated via 'publickey' method
```

P.S.

The configured path for a file containing authorized keys (**SFTPAuthorizedUserKeys**) can use the **%u** variable, which will be interpolated with the name of the user being authenticated. This feature supports having per-user files of authorized keys that reside in a central location, rather than requiring (or allowing) users to manage their own authorized keys. For example:

```
SFTPAuthorizedUserKeys file:/etc/sftp/authorized_keys/%u
```

> I want several clients to be able to store files on my server. Each client should not be able to see any other client's files. And I do not want to litter my server with dozens of user accounts, so I'd like an easily manageable solution for the clients to share a user account and still have no access to eachother's files.

with ProFTPD it's possible too. You just need a little modify my initial configuration

```
<VirtualHost sftp.example.net>
    ...   
    SFTPAuthorizedUserKeys file:/etc/proftpd/sftp_authorized_keys
    AuthUserFile /etc/proftpd/sftp_users.passwd

    CreateHome on 0700 dirmode 0700 uid 99 gid 99

    RewriteHome on
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteLog /var/log/proftpd/rewrite.log
    RewriteCondition %m REWRITE_HOME
    RewriteRule (.*) /vhosts/backup/%u
</VirtualHost>
```

And create one virtual account

```
# ftpasswd --passwd --file /etc/proftpd/sftp_users.passwd --sha512 --gid 99 --uid 99 --shell /sbin/nologin --name user1 --home /vhosts/backup
```

That's all. For every additional account all you need is to add his public key to the /etc/proftpd/sftp_authorized_keys

Note: the file must contain new line in the end! It's important.

Comment: Thank you for your detailled answer.
However, I don't see how this would help me achieve my main goal of using only one user account for many clients that should not be able to see eachother's files. (And be easily manageable by a script.)
Reading my original question again, I admit that it might not have been entirely obvious what I wanted to achieve. Sorry for that.

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: Okay, with a small change, this actually works nicely, thanks!

To make sure users cannot access other users' files by guessing their username (or to flood my server by misusing the CreateHome function), the authorized_keys file needs to be user-specific, like /foo/authorized_keys.d/%u.

Answer (score 6):

> the `chroot=...` does not work.

No, there is nothing like that in the manual page for `sshd`, describing the format of `authorized_keys` file.

If you would put chroot into `command=`, you would not be able to use `internal-sftp`, because it is substitution of internal function call inside `sshd`.

Recommended way is set up more users, if you need separation. You might also use arguments to `internal-sftp`, if you don't need strict separation (for exaxmple just different working directories), such as

```
command="internal-sftp -d /backup/client-1/data" ssh-rsa (key1)
```

There is also possible to limit amount of requests using `-P` option as in manual page for `sftp-server`.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I came up with another simple solution that works fine, too, at least in my use-case:

Every client connects to the server with the same user account and possibly even the same key (doesn't matter). OpenSSH chroots into a directory that has the following structure:

```
d--x--x---   dark-folder
drwxr-x---   |- verylongrandomfoldername1
drwxr-x---   |- verylongrandomfoldername2
drwxr-x---   `- ...
```

Together with the backup command, the server tells the client the folder name that it should put its files into. The folder names are 64-byte random strings that are virtually unguessable, so every client can only really access its own folder, even though the others are "somewhere out there in the dark".

the d--x--x-- mode on dark-folder ensures that every client can enter the folder (and the folders below), but cannot list its contents or create any new entries.

The subfolders are created by the backup server process and the connection between client and folder is stored (among other things) in an sqlite db.